# React navigation 5.0 undefined params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

[Passing data from one screen to another screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwA68.png)

```
    <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() =>
              this.props.navigation.navigate("CourseListBySubject", {
                cateoryId: subject.id,
              })
            }
          >
```

[Tried to get param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEJcu.png)

```
    render() {
    //const { categoryId } = this.props.route.params;
    console.log(this.props.route);
    return <Text>Test</Text>;
  }
```

[Param is undefined in console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oowe.png)

```
Object { 
"key": "CourseListBySubject-l0ynFMFcdC5uToYiupsGr", 
"name": "CourseListBySubject", 
"params": undefined, 
}
```

Can anyone help to get param data in second screen?

Comment: You are passing the params correctly, can you post the navigation config too?

Comment: Are you certain that `CourseListBySubject` is not a nested navigator? See [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#passing-params-to-nested-navigators)

Comment: You have a typo in the first code block. Missing the "g" there

Comment: Facing the same issue